# Best way to write to CSV and append to list simulatenously in Python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, export-to-csv

**Background:**
I have the following code the uses Selenium to find a list of links from this [Simply Recipe Index URL](https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/) and stores them in a `linklist` list. The code then iterates through a `linklist` and for every link, it will download recipe text, before storing the data in a `recipe_list`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium
import time
import csv

#set up chromedriver for WINDOWS
driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/"
driver.get(url) 
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

#set up chromedriver for MAC
driver=webdriver.Chrome("/Users/williamforsyth/Documents/uc_davis/Homework_Repos/group-project-2/Kathryn/chromedriver")
url = "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/"
driver.get(url) 
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

linklist=[]
links=soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    linklist.append(link)
linklist_text=[]
for i in range(164,1068):
    linklist_text.append(linklist[i].text)

recipe_list=[]
for link in linklist_text:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    target=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(link)
    target.click()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    cards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grd-title-link")
    for i in range(0,len(cards)):
        try:
            newcards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grd-title-link")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            newcards[i].click()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            recipe=driver.find_element_by_id("sr-recipe-callout")
            recipe_list.append(recipe.text)
            driver.back()
            time.sleep(0.3)
        except:
            continue
    driver.get(url)
```

**Issue:**
 This code wasn't written with a feature I'd now like to implement, in mind, which is that I'd like to append the `recipe.text` from every loop to a csv file. This is the code that I'd like to try and append to a CSV as well as what the code does now, which is append to the **recipe_list**

```
    recipe_list.append(recipe.text)
```

Is there a simple way to implement this, without having to rework the entire code?

Comment: You want a CSV with a single column of recipe text?

Comment: @tdelaney - yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to "..append the recipe.text from every loop to a csv file"

If you just want to dump it to file each iteration of your TRY loop, then you could import a reader and replace your "recipe_list.append(recipe.text)" with something like:

```
import csv

with open('recipe_output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(recipe.text)
```

Set the "with open()" and "writer =" lines somewhere before the loop begins, and use this "writer.writerow" line to replace your current "recipe_list.append(recipe.text)" line. This will give you a file dump for every loop into a CSV file, instead of dumping the lot from your appended list at the end

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to write a CSV containing a single column of recipe text is to use the csv module after `recipe_list` is written:

```
import csv
with open('recipies.csv', mode='w', newline='') as fileobj:
    csv.writer(fileobj).writerows([col] for col in recipe_list)
```

This will overwrite the recipies file each time you run it. You could use `mode='a'` to append.

Comment: Very grateful for your contribution...Would it be possible to show where exactly in my code I should implement this. I put the first line of code (with open...) just before my for loop and the last line of your code (csv.writer...) after 'driver.get(url). I got no errors, but nothing appended to the csv file

Comment: Put it at the very end after the for loop that fills `recipe_list`. At that point you've got all of the rows of 1 column in the list and writerows will write them all.... except I just realized I have a bug. I need to make each item in `recipe_list` into its own list or it will write a bunch of columns of 1 character apiece. Blush. It'll be fixed.

Comment: Thanks tdelaney - it unfortunately seems I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax. It's referencing the 'recipe_list' right at the end of the code.

Comment: Oops. You know that fix that's too simple to bother testing? Well... fixed it.